# How to create "target","_blank" using JS HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to create `_blank` with js HTML DOM, is it correct?

```
var a = document.createElement('a');

a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(contacts[i][j]));

a.setAttribute("href","http://www.facebook.com/", contacts[i][j],"target","_blank" );

td.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should spilt the `setAttribute` like:

```
a.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.facebook.com/');

a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) it takes only two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method accept only 2 parameters

1. name is the name of the attribute as a string.
2. value is the desired new value of the attribute.

---

```
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(contacts[i][j]));
   a.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.facebook.com/');
   a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
   td.appendChild(a);
```